# How to get first datagridview's cell value if it is not selected?

Tags: c#

I want to take first datagridview's value without to use selection mode:fullselectedrow. The example below doesnt work.

```
MessageBox.Show(AppointmentGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

I get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Comment: What about `MessageBox.Show(AppointmentGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());`?

Comment: Thank you it worked. One last question how can i delete current row if only one cell is selected?

Comment: Something like `AppointmentGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(AppointmentGrid.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the first cell in the DataGridView:

```
var cellValue = AppointmentGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

To delete the row of a single selected cell:

```
AppointmentGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(AppointmentGrid.SelectedCells[‌​0].RowIndex);
```

Mind though; you do need to do some bounds checking so that the indices are not out of range.